# Weird "No ip address could be resolved" in RabbitMQ .NET client

Tags: .net, .net-core, rabbitmq

I am experiencing a weird issue with RabbitMQ client v6.2.1 in my .NET Core 3.0 app. Many queues are consumed flawlessly but two to be used for sending messages throw "No ip address could be resolved for XXX" even if I point a direct IP address instead of XXX. It fails on the very last line in my code sample. What's wrong with my ConnectionFactory definition? I don't work with Ipv6, it's 100% for sure:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
            NetworkRecoveryInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, settings.NetworkRecoveryIntervalInMs),
            HostName = settings.Host,
            TopologyRecoveryEnabled = true,
            Ssl = settings.UseSSL ? new SslOption
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Version = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
                ServerName = settings.Host,
                CertPath = settings.Cert,
                CertPassphrase = settings.CertPassphrase,
                AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors
            } : null,
            VirtualHost = settings.VirtualHost,
            Port = int.Parse(settings.Port),
            UserName = settings.UserName,
            Password = settings.Password
        };

        return connectionFactory.CreateConnection(settings.ClientName);
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't know if you've solved this or not, I've had the same issue recently with a Xamarin app using RabbitMQ. It tries to create a socket with AddressFamily.Unspecified, which is not allowed, it just blows up. The result is this cryptic 'No ip address can be found' exception. If you set the default address family before you use the connection factory then it works just fine:

```
ConnectionFactory.DefaultAddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork;
```

or

```
ConnectionFactory.DefaultAddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6;
```

Of course, you're now limited to only using IPv4 or IPv6 addresses but that's not a problem for me (not right now anyway).